# Type Problems chaining CaseOf Statements with Parsec

Tags: haskell, types, parsec

I'm learning haskell, and my current project is writing a parser to read a text file representation of a database.

At the moment, I'm setting up the code for reading individual fields of tables. In the text file, fields look either like this:

```
name type flags format
```

or this:

```
name type       format
```

This gives the trouble of having to account for cases of there being a flag or not being a flag. I solved this in my main function like this:

```
main = case parse fieldsWithFlags "(test)" testLine of
        Left err  -> noFlags
        Right res -> print res
   where noFlags = case parse fieldsWithoutFlags "(test)" testLine of
                        Left err -> print err
                        Right res -> print res
```

If I understand correctly, this says "If it's a line that doesn't have flags, try to parse it as such; otherwise, return an error." It prints the correct results for any "testLine" I throw at it, and returns errors if both options fail. However, when I try to pull this out into its own function, like this:

```
field :: Either ParseError Field
field = case parse fieldsWithFlags "(test)" testLine of
            Left err  -> noFlags
            Right res -> return Right res
        where noFlags = case parse fieldsWithoutFlags "(test)" testLine of
                           Left err -> return Left err
                           Right res -> return Right res
main = case field of
       Left err -> print err
       Right res -> print res
```

GHC gives me:

```
haskellParsing.hs:58:26:
Couldn't match expected type `Either ParseError Field'
with actual type `b0 -> Either b0 b0'
In the expression: noFlags
In a case alternative: Left err -> noFlags
In the expression:
  case parse fieldsWithFlags "(test)" testLine of {
    Left err -> noFlags
    Right res -> return Right res }
```

I've played around with this a lot, but just can't get it working. I'm sure there's a much more clear-headed way of doing this, so any suggestions would be welcome - but I also want to understand why this isn't working.

Full code is at: http://pastebin.com/ajG6BkPU

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need the `return` in your cases. Once you wrap something in `Left` or `Right` it is in `Either`; since you only need a `Either ParseError Field`, the `Left` and `Right` do not need an extra `return`.

Also, you should be able to simplify your `parseFields` significantly. You can write a new parser that looks like this:

```
fields = try fieldsWithFlags <|> fieldsWithoutFlags
```

what this does is run the first one and, if it fails, backtrack and run the second one. The `try` is important because this is what enables the backtracking behavior. You have to backtrack because `fieldsWithFlags` consumes some of the input that you care about.

Now you should be able to just use `fields` in your `main` function.

Comment: Thanks! I don't quite understand how return factors into the wrapping, but I"ll look into that. On compiling, this works.

Comment: Oh wow, I was worrying about whether it would consume input, too! Two birds with one stone. You rock!

Comment: Essentially, `return` "injects" a value into `Either`. Since you already did that normally (via `Left` or `Right`) you don't need to do it again. For `Either`, `return` is actually just defined as `Right`.

Comment: `return` is *not* the same as return in languages like python, perl, and C.  It encases a value in the current `Monad`'s standard armor... Exactly what that means depends upon the `Monad`.  It does not cause control to leave the current function.

Comment: @pat: That's a good clarification. I think the name was originally chosen to make do-notation look cute (like an imperative program), but it seems to cause nothing but confusion. A better name would be `unit` or `pure`.

Answer (score 1):

Since the form without flags is almost identical to that with flags (just that the flags are missing), the alternative can be pushed down to where the flags might appear.  In this way, you avoid backtracking over name and type in with-flags, just to parse them again in without-flags.  We could combine the with and without fields parsers like this:

```
fields = do
  iName <- getFieldName
  spaces
  iType <- getDataType
  spaces
  iFlag <- option "" $ try getFlag
  spaces
  iFormat <- getFormat
  newline -- this was only present in without flags, was that intended?
  return $ Field iName iType iFlag iFormat
```

Comment: The code duplication was bothering me, I was wondering if there was a way to do this. Thank you for showing me it - it looks a lot better.

The endline bit was something I was playing with, and meant to take out before putting it in pastebin. My apologies.